# use of getter methods isn't better than direct object properties?

Tags: php, json, object

I want to create a Stripe webhook, in some places I need to have some conditions like:

```
if ($event->object->data[0]->blah == "blah") {
```

Instead of these long conditions, isn't it better to pass all event data to another class and just use getter methods like below?

```
if ($object->getBlah() == "blah") {
```

No disadvantage for performance? Or this is not recommended because of performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>PHP7 is out, you don't need to optimize anymore.</strike>

You don't need to worry about performance in these cases. This is hardly going to be a bottleneck of your application.

It's much more important to write code that it's easier to understand for other developers and for you.

It's better because then you hide all the Stripe internal logic inside of your class. Then other parts of your application do not need to care or remember how Stripe stores data, they just use the method you provide.

It's much easier to understand and much easier to extend.